# Elastic Beanstalk Python platform failed to retrieve logs request (python 3.8+)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So far i have tried 3.8/3.9/3.11. All failed to retrieve logs even with the sample application.

i read docs and did some research but found nothing from the internet. Please advise! Usually it should allow you to query the last 100 lines of log or request the full log which AWS will make you download the entire log in a zip file.

I found a post that people suggest to SSH and export/read logs in there but... that's not what the Elastic Beanstalk is made for.

Comment: If you can't find some of the environment's instance logs you expect in CloudWatch Logs, probably your IAM role lacks the required IAM permissions

Comment: well that was it, for some reasons i let AWS create the role for it and it were missing these 3 perms: "AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier", "AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier", "AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Arpit Jain][1],

i finally got it to download the logs by adding these permm to the role:

"AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier",
"AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier",
"AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker"

you may need less though...
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12326605/arpit-jain